# Android ViewPager: Show particular page no matter in which direction user swipes

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have really worked A LOT trying to get this running, without any results.
I want my ViewPager to go to the next page, no matter if I swipe to the right, left, top, down. The pages should be like a stack of cards and the top one is always swiped away.

I have tried to extend the class ViewPager, with an overridden

`public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { ... }`

method, but this seemed to me to be a little too much effort for this task.

The other idea was to create a gesture listener and set it to the ViewPager via

`setOnTouchListener();`

but as soon as I did manage to get what I wanted, the transition of pages stopped working.

Lastly, I found a method in ViewPager called

`determineTargetPage(...)`

which sounds like it could be what I need, but it is private :-(

I am really out of ideas and it seems to me this should not be such a hard task to worry about it so much. Do you have any recommendations on how to proceed? I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: `StackView` would appear to be a better starting point, since it already implements the stack-of-cards, swipe-the-top-one-away logic.

Comment: Holy cow, this sounds exactly like what I need. I will look into this immediately

Comment: The problem is, that StackView is even more "magical" than ViewPager. With ViewPager I can at least easily add GestureListeners etc., but StackView is like a blackbox...
I have implemented one now, but it also automatically allows for swiping the old cards back and I don't know where to manipulate that...